# swift Perfect server deployment in Amazon AWS Buildpack

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, buildpack, perfect

Am trying to deploy my web service written in swift, I don't see the web-root folder and not sure where to create the folder. Anybody have tried, please help me to copy the source code and start the server.

Comment: Depends on how you provisioned things.  I created an Ubuntu 16 AWS instance with apache 2 and it put the root at /var/www/html, but that doesn't mean that's how they all do it.

Comment: Thanks! Am new to swift web server side programming. Do you have any tutorial/docs for that. Your help much appreciated. Nowhere i could find a help for swift web service in AWS using Perfect server.

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't write my server side code in Swift.  You're locking yourself into an OS choice at this point by doing that.  You're better off using PHP or some other more common web scripting language.  I just had a client move his hosting service from a mac to another platform.  If I had done his server side in Swift, the move might not have gone as easily.

Comment: yes, i do agree. I don't know any other scripting language other than JS. am iOS developer with swift experience and am in need of dedicated web services  and website. so thought of writing it in Swift. Moreover, swift is so simple

Answer (score 0):

so, can you tell me what you have done so far, in relation to getting the AWS instance up and running ? Did you use the AWS instructions from [here](http://perfect.org/aws-buildpack-for-perfect-and-swift.html)?

Once you have the instance up and running, there are several ways to deploy your code, such as a git pull. By default, the webroot folder for the PerfectServer is created in the current working directory when you run the app. There are several command line options to define the location of libraries, server port and location of webroot.

With more information, I'd be happy to help get you running.

Comment: those issues resolved now. this is @Dsp1589 in Gitter :) . its up and running. am developing HTML static files. Will message in gitter.

Comment: cool. wasn't sure if that was a question that had been handled elsewhere or not.

Comment: Actually in aws, I did not know about starting the server. Then I found out from tutorial and port fwded to 8181. Still I am looking for a way to listen to std port 80 directly